# is it possible to make a UITableView's rows pressable while in edit mode?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView in my app that doesn't really make sense to be ever out of edit mode. I still want the user to drill in and edit things on another screen though. Is it possible to make the row press able while editing is enabled?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[UITableView allowsSelectionDuringEditing]`. One of the first table attributes in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. And thanks @sgermain06 too - its the thought that counts ;).